# Unable to remove a value from a text file using -sed

Tags: bash, sed, terminal

I'm trying to remove an ID number from a text file using a series of commands (using terminal), but they don't seem to be working. I need to remove the number and the associated "ID" text

Text in File:
{"id":"098765432"}

Commands I've been using (but don't seem to be working):

```
sed -i.bak 's/"id":[0-9]\{1,\},//g' ./Filename.txt
sed -i.bak 's/"id":"[0-9]\{1,\}",//g' ./Filename.txt
sed -i.bak 's/"id":"[0-9]\{9,\}",//g' ./Filename.txt
sed -i.bak 's/"id":[0-9]\{9,\},//g' ./Filename.txt
sed -i.bak 's/"[0-9]\{1,\}",//g' ./Filename.txt
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate json with sed? Can you show the input document and your expected output?

Comment: If that is JSON, take a look at [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). You could use something like `jq 'del(.id)' filename`.

Comment: @hek2mgl No, I'm trying to manipulate a text file. A simply .txt file

Comment: So the expected response is for the text above to be removed from a text file.

Comment: Remove the comma before `//`. Second command should work then.

Comment: @Wintermute Great, thanks! :)

Comment: For clarity, I'd also recommend simplifying your regular expressions. `[0-9]\{1,\}`, while likely correct, is hard to read. I'm never sure which tool requires backslashes or does or doesn't support bounds. You'd get the same result using `[0-9][0-9]*`. And depending on your platform, you may be able to use ERE (instead of BRE) by including a `-r` or `-E` option to sed, simplifying this to `[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Wintermute already noted in the comment, the problem is in the comma before //. However, I am going to explain the whole line, just so the others may understand it completely, in case something is not clear to those who come across this question later.

So, the proper command that will satisfy your requirement is:

```
sed -i.bak 's/"id":"[0-9]\{1,\}"//g' ./Filename.txt
```

**sed** is the command that calls [stream editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).

Flag **-i** is the flag used to represent editing files in place (it makes backup if extension is supplied). In this case, extension written is **.bak** and indeed the backup file (containing initial context of our file) is created with the original name + the extension provided.

Argument **'s/"id":"[0-9]{1,}"//g'** is the argument given to the sed command.

Since this argument ([regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in it) was the cause of the problem, I am going to explain it in detail.

First part we should notice is that its structure is **s/Regex/Replacement/g** where

*Regex = "id":"[0-9]{1,}"*

*Replacement = nothing (literally nothing, not even blank space)*

So basically, as described by [Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), **s** stands for substitution. **Regex** is the part we will replace with the **Replacement**. At the end, letter **g** means that we will change more than just one occurrence of this regex per line (without g, it would replace just the first occurrence in every line, no matter how many are there).

And at the end we have **./Filename.txt**, which is the source file we are applying this command on (**./** means that the file is in the same directory from where we are running this command).

***About the regex used ("id":"[0-9]{1,}"):***

It starts with the literals ("id":") and this part will match literally any part in the file which is exactly the same as this one. Next, we have ([0-9]{1,}), which means that we want to, in addition to the first part, look for the at least one occurrence of a number (but it can be more of them, as the matched example from the question shows).

Now you may understand why comma caused this problem. There is no comma in the original text in the file. Thus, none of the commands tried (since all of them contain comma) worked. Of course, some of them have even more reasons.

**EDIT:** As @ghoti pointed out, **replacement** is not a regex. It is the string we will put at the place(s) that are found by our regex expression. So in this case, our replacement is blank string (since we want to delete the specified part).

Comment: Your explanation of `s/Regex1/Regex2/g` is incorrect. In a sed substitution, the notation is `s/regex/replacement/`. The replacement string is *not* a regex, it is just text, possibly with "translated" bits that represent matches from regex in the first part. For example `s/e\([aeiou]\)/E\1/` will capitalize an "e" that preceeds a vowel, but no other "e".

Comment: @ghoti You're completely right. I edited my answer. :)